# Moment.Js: Offsetting dates using UTC and Timezone offset

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs

I am trying to adjust a time using a timezone offset and a UTC timestamp.

I am running the following code:

```
var date = {
    utc: '2013-10-16T21:31:51',
    offset: -480
}

var returnDate = moment(date.utc).utc().zone(date.offset).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');
```

What I am expecting is: `10/16/2013 1:31 PM` but I am ending up with `10/17/2013 9:31 AM`

Comment: What does the date look like if you remove the `.utc().zone(date.offset)`? So that way you call just `.format()` on it.

Comment: Also, if looking at the documentation [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and scroll down a little bit. It reads, "Unless you specify a timezone offset, parsing a string will create a date in the current timezone."

Comment: I've posted bad data, let me correct this. sec

Comment: It looks like this: 10/16/2013 9:31 PM with `moment(date.utc).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');`

Comment: What is the current timezone of the server this is running on? If it is not in UTC, you are passing in a UTC date already, and then calling `.utc()` on it, which is further advancing the time.

Comment: I'm unsure of the server time, these dates are coming from a database of events, when they occur. When I use `moment(date.utc).zone(date.zone).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');` I end up with `10/17/2013 9:31 AM ` again

Comment: I think if you are going to be adjusting for timezone then you will have to become sure of the server timezone because moment.js is parsing the date from the users browser.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
var date = {
  utc: '2013-10-16T21:31:51',
  offset: 480
}

var returnDate = moment.utc(date.utc).zone(date.offset).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');
```

If you noticed, I changed the offset to a positive number. This gave the desired result. If the offset was left at `-480` the output was `10/17/2013 5:31 AM`.

There is a [moment#UTC](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) method that initializes the date as UTC vs. local time.

Comment: For other's stumbling on this post, you can use a string for the `offset` that's perhaps more legible: `zone('-07:00')` (PST example)

Comment: `moment.zone()` is deprecated after moment 2.9.0

Comment: the method zone() is deprecated, everyone should use utcOffset() instead see here https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1779

Answer (score 2):

I use the [jsTimezoneDetect](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) library to determine the timezone name instead of the offset.

Then use this on a UTC timestamp:

```
timestamp = moment.tz(timestamp, tz.name());
timestamp.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');
```