# How do you format a moment in local time after changing the default timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a timestamp, which I'm formatting with [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment("2015-03-24T09:47:31.042Z").format("LLL Z")
"March 24, 2015 10:47 AM +01:00"
```

Due to the nature of our application, we're [setting a default timezone for momentjs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/), which affects all rendered moments:

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/Los_Angeles")
moment("2015-03-24T09:47:31.042Z").format("LLL Z")
"March 24, 2015 2:47 AM -07:00"
```

So far, so great. But now I want to display the local time in one specific spot in the application, but momentjs will of course use the provided default timezone:

```
moment().format("LLL Z")
"March 24, 2015 2:52 AM -07:00"
```

How can I construct a moment instance that uses the local timezone again?

I tried using `moment.tz(timestamp,null)`, but that simply uses GMT.

Comment: using offset might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144423/moment-js-offsetting-dates-using-utc-and-timezone-offset

Comment: @Tanner: Indeed. Cool, I'll have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by @Tanner in the comments and the answers in [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript), I was able to figure it out.

You can set the UTC offset of a moment using [`utcOffset`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/). Combined with `Date.getTimezoneOffset`, you can render the moment in local time again:

```
moment("2015-03-24T09:47:31.042Z")
  .utcOffset(-new Date().getTimezoneOffset())
  .format("LLL Z")

"March 24, 2015 10:47 AM +01:00"
```