# Get UTC Offset from date with different timezone

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Im struggling with date issues and would love to get some help. 
i want to get to offset from UTC by the timezone name.
I am getting my date from the server in this format:
`"July 11, 2016::11:09:43 AM IDT"` (Time Zone in this case is IDT- but can be any other timezone).
I want to be able to get the offset from IDT (in this case) to UTC.
Is there any way to figure it out?

thanks!
livnat:)

Comment: Maybe: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.Js: Offsetting dates using UTC and Timezone offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144423/moment-js-offsetting-dates-using-utc-and-timezone-offset)

Comment: i'v tried Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset() (mozilla) didnt work .

Comment: its not duplicate cause i want to get to offset by the timezone name.

Comment: Offset from IDT to UTC is constant?

Comment: yes but IDT is just an example and it can change to any other timezone (i get the timezone from the server which is different in different countries)

Comment: So you want a table of timezone offsets?

Comment: @Libbi : try this, var YourUTC = moment.utc(YourDate variable).valueOf();

Comment: @SagarR not working..:( im getting "NAN" :(

Comment: @Libbi : 
Hi,I tried this ,moment.utc('July 11, 2016 11:09:43 AM').format('DD MMM YYYY HH:MM'), its working perfect for me.you could try with hardcoded date.

Comment: @SagarR  - but how u set the timezone? i want the moment.utc to get the timezone as well

Comment: i think that maybe i haven't explain myself very well,i have a string that contains a date and timezone(not utc!) i want to get from this text the utc offset.

Comment: Note that *getTimezoneOffset* returns the host system offset, not the offset of the date string. To extract the time zone from the string you must parse it and transform it to a time zone offset, per Matt Johnson's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you examine a list of time zone abbreviations and their corresponding offsets, such as [the list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) or [the list on timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/), you may be able to find that `IDT` is an abbreviation for Israel Daylight Time, and is equal to UTC+3.  However, upon further examination you'll also find that there are many abbreviations that are ambiguous.  For example:

- `CST` could be any of:

  - Central Standard Time (UTC-6)
  - China Standard Time (UTC+8)
  - Cuba Standard Time (UTC-5)
- `BST` could be any of:

  - British Summer Time (UTC+1)
  - Bangladesh Standard Time (UTC+6)
  - Bougainville Standard Time (UTC+11)

... and many others.

You'll also find that two lists I mentioned are not identical.  That's because in general, time zone abbreviations are a *convention*, not a *standard*.

Therefore, if all you have is an abbreviation, and you want to cover all the time zones of the world, then you cannot uniquely identify the time zone.

That said, if you can limit your list to a set of predefined, non-conflicting abbreviations, then you could certainly work out a mapping table on your own.  Alternatively, if you have additional information such as the *country*, then you can also use that information to disambiguate.

Comment: thx!! so actually i need to get something like "Europe/Paris" and use moment.js to get the utc offset?

Comment: That would be one way, yes.